# Select unique ID's only by oldest date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the below query that I am trying to modify to get only 1 unique `PO_ID` that has the oldest date (`DUE_DT`)

```
SELECT DISTINCT (CONVERT(CHAR(10),B.PO_DT,121)) AS 'ENTERED DATE', B.BUSINESS_UNIT, A.DEPTID, B.PO_ID,
 B.PO_STATUS, B.VENDOR_ID, B.BUYER_ID, 
 D.RECV_REQ, (CONVERT(CHAR(10),E.DUE_DT,121)) AS 'DUE_DT'
FROM ((((PS_PO_HDR B 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_PO_LINE_DISTRIB A ON  B.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND B.PO_ID = A.PO_ID ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_VENDOR C ON  C.VENDOR_ID = B.VENDOR_ID ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_PO_LINE D ON  
B.BUSINESS_UNIT = D.BUSINESS_UNIT AND B.PO_ID = D.PO_ID ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_PO_LINE_SHIP E ON  D.BUSINESS_UNIT = E.BUSINESS_UNIT AND D.PO_ID = E.PO_ID AND D.LINE_NBR = E.LINE_NBR )
 WHERE ( B.PO_STATUS IN ('A','D','O')
   AND D.CANCEL_STATUS IN ('A','X','O','C')
   AND E.DUE_DT BETWEEN dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()-11), 0) AND dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), -3)
     AND B.RECV_STATUS NOT IN ('C','M','R')
     AND D.RECV_REQ = 'Y')
  ORDER BY 2, 3, 4
```

Here is sample date I am currently getting:

```
ENTERED_DT   BUSINESS_UNIT  DEPTID  PO_ID        PO_STATUS   VENDOR_ID   BUYER_ID   RECV_REQ    DUE_DT
2020-07-13   11000          624     A010035568   D           UNITED      NOTT       Y           2020-07-13
2020-07-08   11000          659     A010035426   D           SCIMED      NOTT       Y           2020-07-15
2020-07-08   11000          659     A010035426   D           SCIMED      NOTT       Y           2020-07-09
2020-07-09   11000          659     A010035468   D           SCIMED      NOTT       Y           2020-07-10
```

In this case for rows 3 and 4 (Where `PO_ID` is duplicated) I only want to return one row, and I would want the row with the oldest date (`2020-07-09`) returned.

I tried addinga `NOT EXISTS` condition into the `WHERE` clause however it appears to be filtering out too many results now:

```
 ....
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(*) , BB.DUE_DT
                FROM PS_PO_LINE_SHIP BB
                LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_PO_LINE DD ON DD.BUSINESS_UNIT = BB.BUSINESS_UNIT
                 AND DD.PO_ID = BB.PO_ID AND DD.LINE_NBR = BB.LINE_NBR
                WHERE BB.PO_ID = B.PO_ID
                AND BB.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT
                GROUP BY BB.DUE_DT
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

**EDIT:** I changed the query to get the MIN DUE_DT (`MIN((CONVERT(CHAR(10),E.DUE_DT,121)))` however in trying to calculate the difference in number of days between the `PO_DT` and the `DUE_DT` I am getting a GROUP BY error.

I added this column to my SELECT statement:
`DATEDIFF(DAY, E.DUE_DT, B.PO_DT) AS DateDiff` however it is saying it's missing from the `Group By`. If I add it to the Group By then I re-introduce the duplicate PO_ID's. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried querying for the MINIMUM value in the your date column (GROUP BY the columns 2,3,4)?

Comment: All of your left joins (seemingly) are meaningless outer joins because of the `where` conditions.  And why all the parentheses in the `FROM` clause?

Comment: I edited the post above with an update.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at SQL Server's [last_value function](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-last_value-function/)

Applied to your case, it would look something like this:

`LAST_VALUE(PO_ID) OVER(ORDER BY DUE_DT) OLDEST_PO_ID`